# How to update sql table column value dynamicllay based on another value?

Tags: sql-server

I have one table with the following structure and some values :

PK_ID      Webinar_Name                   Start_Date                          Is_Active

1                                 w1                               3/1/2016                              True

2                                w2                                1/7/2016                            True

3                                w3                                   4/9/2016                             True

Now i want the **Is_Active** column value to be updated dynamically (i.e : **NOT** after update,insert and delete) based on the date.. if its matches the current date so the **Is_Active** column value will set to be false.

I've tried to use triggers but it should be after some action like insert and update which is conflicts with my requirements.

I appreciate any help . thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a computed column:

```
alter table t add Is_Active as (case when cast(start_date as date) = cast(getdate() as date) then 0 else 1 end)
```

Of course, you might need to remove the column first.

Note:  this uses 1 for true and 0 for false.  These constants are not defined in SQL Server.  You can use whatever values you like.

Comment: You'd probably also want to remove the time part from the date returned by GetDate(), otherwise it'll only match at precisely midnight on the start date

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you should be able to use a computed column for this, though I've never tried it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188300.aspx

I guess it'd look something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE webinars ADD ActiveFlag AS
    CASE WHEN Start_Date = CAST(GetDate() AS date) THEN 'True'
    ELSE 'False' END
```